# My ajax code is not send value to other php page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My ajax code is not send value to other php page??

I want to delete value coming from database ajax code get id that come from database but not sent to other php page where delete code.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
     function deleteBox(id){
       if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")){
         var dataString =  id;

         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "del.php",
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
           success: function(){

           }    
         });
       }
     }
   </script>
```

Comment: try hash in data. Like this:  "data: {'id': id}"

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
var dataString =  id;
        $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "del.php?datastring="+id,
       //data: dataString,
       cache: false,
       success: function(){
    }
    });
```

**or**

```
var dataString =  id;
        $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "del.php",
       data: {datastring:id},
       cache: false,
       success: function(){
    }
    });
```

Comment: The OP would certainly be happy about an **explanation**.

Comment: you mention variable name only in your code(data: dataString) not value so this code( data: {datastring:id}) var name and value so its works...

Comment: call deleteBox function code
 <?php echo' <td width="100"> <a href="javascript:void()"><img alt="Delete" title="Delete" width="15" src="images/cancel.png" onclick=deleteBox("'.$rows['id'].'") border="0"></a>' ?>

Answer (score 0):

please correct this in ajax call. you can pass the data from one page to another page using data. like data : {var1:value1,var2:value2,var3:value3}

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "del.php",
           data: {dataString: dataString},
           cache: false,
           success: function(){

           }    
         });
```

Comment: The OP would certainly be happy about an **explanation**.

Answer (score 0):

send `data` with parameter `name` and `value` not only value, like this

```
data: {'id':dataString},
```